# Batch Migration of VS 2008 Solutions/Projects to VS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, migration

Does anyone know a fast way of batch migrating VS 2008 Solutions/Projects to VS 2010? A simple test using the Migration Wizard shows that amongst others, the ToolVersion attribute is automatically changed to 4.0, the NoWarn key gets new exceptions added and a couple of other things...

If there is no other way, I will have to do it manually using the Migration Wizard. However, I'd like to have a simpler way... since I got a lot of projects...

Answer (score 2):

You can use the command line to skip the wizard window.  Just open the Visual Studio 2010 Command prompt and type:

```
devenv /Upgrade \Path\To\Solution.sln
```

That will upgrade all of the projects in your solution using the default settings.